# Route [admin.index] not defined

Tags: php, laravel-5

working with Laravel 5.8 and I have following href link,

```
href="{{route('admin.index')}}"
```

and my web.php route is like this,

```
Route::get('/admin.index', function () {
    return view('admin.index')->name('admin.index');
});
```

but I got following error message here
`Route [admin.index] not defined. (View: F:\2020 technologies\laravel\bestbrandtoday\resources\views\_includes\nav\admin.blade.php)`

how could I fix this problem?

Comment: Your `->name('admin.index');` is in the wrong spot... It should be `Route::get(...)->name('admin.index');`. Right now, you're naming your `view()`, which does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax for route name declarations is this:

```
Route::get('/admin.index', function () {
    return view('admin.index');
})->name('admin.index');
```

Answer (score 0):

The name goes on the route, not on the response:

```
Route::get('/admin.index', function () {
    return view('admin.index');
})->name('admin.index');
```

As a side note, your actual route probably shouldn't have a period in it, so you can use just `/admin` or `/admin/index`

Comment: use these following route `Route::get('/admin/index', function () {
    return view('admin.index')->name('admin.index');
});` but not success here

Comment: You had missed the part about moving the name outside of the function. It belongs on the route, not the view.